# idempotency_key must be set error using Square API

Tags: php, api, square-connect, idempotent

Trying to use Square e-commerce API. When running a test charge, I recieve the following response:

```
object(stdClass)#14 (1) {
  ["errors"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
     object(stdClass)#13 (4) {
      ["category"]=>
      string(21) "INVALID_REQUEST_ERROR"
      ["code"]=>
      string(26) "MISSING_REQUIRED_PARAMETER"
      ["detail"]=>
      string(17) "Field must be set"
      ["field"]=>
      string(15) "idempotency_key"
    }
  }
}
```

I cant quite work out why it has failed to set the idempotenct_key. I thought this was being dealt with by the uniqid() function. Please advise. My code is as follows:

```
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
# Replace these values. You probably want to start with your Sandbox credentials
# to start: https://docs.connect.squareup.com/articles/using-sandbox/
# The ID of the business location to associate processed payments with.
# If you're testing things out, use a sandbox location ID.
#
# See [Retrieve your business's locations](https://docs.connect.squareup.com/articles/getting-started/#retrievemerchantprofile)
# for an easy way to get your business's location IDs.

# The access token to use in all Connect API requests. Use your *sandbox* access
# token if you're just testing things out.
$access_token = 'REPLACE_ME';

    SquareConnect\Configuration::getDefaultConfiguration()->setAccessToken($access_token);

$locations_api = new \SquareConnect\Api\LocationsApi();

$location_id = $locations_api->listLocations($access_token);
# Helps ensure this code has been reached via form submission
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] != 'POST') {
  error_log("Received a non-POST request");
  echo "Request not allowed";
  http_response_code(405);
  return;
}
# Fail if the card form didn't send a value for `nonce` to the server
$nonce = $_POST['nonce'];
if (is_null($nonce)) {
  echo "Invalid card data";
  http_response_code(422);
  return;
}
$transactions_api = new \SquareConnect\Api\TransactionsApi();
$request_body = array (
  "card_nonce" => $nonce,
  # Monetary amounts are specified in the smallest unit of the applicable currency.
  # This amount is in cents. It's also hard-coded for $1.00, which isn't very useful.
  "amount_money" => array (
    "amount" => 100,
    "currency" => "USD"
  ),
  # Every payment you process with the SDK must have a unique idempotency key.
  # If you're unsure whether a particular payment succeeded, you can reattempt
  # it with the same idempotency key without worrying about double charging
  # the buyer.
  "idempotency_key" => uniqid()
);
# The SDK throws an exception if a Connect endpoint responds with anything besides
# a 200-level HTTP code. This block catches any exceptions that occur from the request.
try {
  $result = $transactions_api->charge($access_token, $location_id, $request_body);
  echo "<pre>";
  print_r($result);
  echo "</pre>";
} catch (\SquareConnect\ApiException $e) {
  echo "Caught exception!<br/>";
  print_r("<strong>Response body:</strong><br/>");
  echo "<pre>"; var_dump($e->getResponseBody()); echo "</pre>";
  echo "<br/><strong>Response headers:</strong><br/>";
  echo "<pre>"; var_dump($e->getResponseHeaders()); echo "</pre>";
}

?>
```

Comment: that is strange, can you tell me which version of the PHP SDK you are using?

Comment: i believe it is 5.4.0

Comment: whoa, that doesn't seem right, that might be the version of PHP that you are running. Do you have a composer.json file? can you tell me what it says next to "square/connect":

Comment: Yes I do. It just says "*" Below is everything I have in that file:

Comment: {
      "require": {
      
        "square/connect": "*"
      }
    }

Comment: Gotcha, what is probably going on then is that you are using a more recent version of the SDK than the sample was written for, and it looks like you are submitting a request with an empty body.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using some outdated sample code. Try the code here: https://github.com/square/connect-api-examples/blob/master/connect-examples/v2/php_payment/process-card.php

The main difference is the lack of an `authorization` parameter in the request.

Comment: Perfect that's worked thanks. I'm using the Sandbox details so no real charging happening at the moment but its showing as a success. Just a thought, as I am struggling to find anything in the documentation, when charging a card, where does the payment get deposited? I cant see it defined anywhere in the code.

Comment: It gets deposited into your square account. I'm not sure I understood your question though

Comment: Tristan, following your advice I have successfully managed to use the API using my sandbox details. However, when testing with my real details it says card declined. I know its not a fault with my account as other purchases on other sites work fine and I am only trying to process a very small amount. I wondered if there was any issue with the way its been set up using the code you have provided above? i.e. is any more info is required? Just reaching out to you on this as I see in your profile you are a developer and Square. Hope you can help.

Comment: Are you able to make a transaction with that card and virtual terminal? Do other cards work? What is the exact response you get back from the API?

Comment: If by virtual terminal you mean when charging with sandbox credentials then yes it is working. And no, I have tried a couple of cards an no joy. The response is as follows:

Comment: Caught exception!
Response body:

object(stdClass)#13 (1) {
  ["errors"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    object(stdClass)#12 (3) {
      ["category"]=>
      string(20) "PAYMENT_METHOD_ERROR"
      ["code"]=>
      string(13) "CARD_DECLINED"
      ["detail"]=>
      string(14) "Card declined."
    }
  }
}

Comment: Response headers:

array(12) {
  [0]=>
  string(29) "HTTP/1.1 402 Payment Required"
  ["Content-Type"]=>
  string(16) "application/json"
  ["Vary"]=>
  string(23) "Origin, Accept-Encoding"
  ["X-Content-Type-Options"]=>
  string(7) "nosniff"
  ["X-Download-Options"]=>
  string(6) "noopen"
  ["X-Frame-Options"]=>
  string(10) "SAMEORIGIN"
  ["X-Permitted-Cross-Domain-Policies"]=>
  string(4) "none"
  ["X-Xss-Protection"]=>
  string(13) "1; mode=block"
  ["Date"]=>
  string(29) "Mon, 12 Jun 2017 19:16:46 GMT"

Comment: ["Keep-Alive"]=>
  string(10) "timeout=60"
  ["Strict-Transport-Security"]=>
  string(17) "max-age=631152000"
  ["content-length"]=>
  string(2) "97"
}

Comment: Hmm. [Virtual Terminal](https://squareup.com/virtual-terminal) is a product inside your Square Dashboard that lets you key in card transactions. Are you sure you got things like zip code correct when generating the nonce?

Comment: Ah ok, spotted that now, that's a cool feature! I have tried two different cards (and triple checked the details for both) and both have declined. Do I need some sort of clearance before I can start taking payments?

Comment: If you were able to use virtual terminal in the Square Dashboard (it displays an error like [this](http://i.imgur.com/Ld8f5MP.png) if you aren't enabled). Then it seems like Square just can't process your card, which seems weird. Where are you located? What is the email your account was created with?

Comment: I'm located in Bristol, England. Do you need a location ID or anything? Email is willmurphy100@gmail.com

Comment: I don't see that you have made any card transactions with that account. Can you try a 1GBP charge on your card (you can refund it afterwards) with virtual terminal to see if you card works? is it possible you are using multiple Square accounts?

Comment: OK I have literally just tried to charge 1 GBP through the virtual terminal on the dashboard. willmurphy100@gmail.com is my only account. And it declines it straight away.

Comment: Well then it is an issue between Square and your card, not an API problem. Is this a card that you use regularly? Which brand card is it? Does [this article](https://squareup.com/help/gb/en/article/5085-accepted-cards) mention anything as to why you card wouldn't work?

Comment: And I'm not seeing any transactions being attempted for the account with your email. Are you sure you are logged into that account?